# Visual Studio 2019 removing first letter(s) from Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using `Console.WriteLine("Text");` to write text to the console but at seemingly random times, VS 2019's debugger ammends the first letter or sometimes 2 letters from the output.

Code: `Console.WriteLine("Operation cancelled.");`, expected output: Operation cancelled, actual output: eration cancelled.

This happened twice and now it's fixed. Is this some issue with timings? A dotnet or VS bug?

Thanks.

Comment: In the console window that opens :)

Comment: Is there any multithreading involved?

Comment: "at seemingly random times" meaning no reliable way to reproduce the problem... That's kinda making it hard to answer. Are you experiencing this when running in debug mode or in release mode? What about when running using ctrl+f5 or when running directly from the bin (or publish) directory?

Comment: Nope, though `Thread.Sleep()` is being used but that statement comes after the `WriteLine()`

Comment: Debug mode @ZoharPeled

Comment: Try running the same project without debugging, see if that still happens. Also, try running it directly from the bin/release (or publish) directory. If it only happens when debugging, it's safe to say VS probably has something to do with it.

Comment: Bug does not happen when running `dotnet run <project>` in a normal command prompt window.